# Data is not stored in mongoDB database - node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, visual-studio-code

I write node.js code and try to insert data into a mongodb database by Postman (post) but the data is not saved, only _id and _v are inserted into the documents ,that are entered automatically. I think the problem is in the body-parser, it is deprecated, but I tried a few options and it remained deprecated. (I'm not sure the problem with bodyparser).The data were inserteded via Postman(post). This is the relevant node.js code:

```
const express = require ('express');
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const router = require ('./routes/api');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
.
.
.
app.use(bodyParser.json());//this bodyParser is deprecated
app.use('/',router);
```

model:

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String, 
        require
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        minlength:8,
        require
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

controller:

```
const User = require ('../models/User');
const newUser = async (req,res)=>{
    let user1 = new User(
        req.body);
        console.log(`${user1} added`);
        try{
            await user1.save();
            res.status(200).json({newUser:user1});
        }
        catch(error){
            res.send(`cant save new user: ${error.message}`)
        }        
}
module.exports = { newUser }
```

This is what I wrote in Postman:

```
{
    "name":"james",
    "password":"12345678"
}
```

and this is the response:

```
{
    "newUser": {
        "_id": "60a68f815019f31cfc098572",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

I would be very happy to get help !!

Comment: Could you please add your db code? Also I dont think it has anything to do with bodyParser. Since it is deprecated, you can use `app.use(express.json())` instead.

Comment: this is the schema of "user":const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String, 
        require
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        minlength:8, 
        require
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

Comment: Please add these model and controller codes in the question itself.

Comment: Yeah I understand but you have to show us the complete code right where you are saving the record in the db. And you didn't add the controller code in the question after deleting from the comments?

Comment: oops sorry, i'm new here and accidently deleted  the comment...  I inserted the data via postman (post, localhost:3000/newUser)

Comment: thank you very much for helping, but i still get the same result: {
    "newUser": {
        "_id": "60a6a7580314072c1c024e67",
        "__v": 0
    }
}   in postman and also in mongo

Comment: Could you please try my answer once again? And let me know whether `req.body` is printing an empty object or not?

Comment: Have you changed `app.use(bodyParser.json())` to `app.use(express.json())` ? Because for me, your code is working now in Postman.

Comment: Thanks for the time you give me, but for some reason the data is not inserted into the DB. I thought maybe I have a problem with Postman and reinstalled, but now I get the result: cant save new user: User validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., Password: Path` password` is required.

Comment: And really the model had the error you wrote with the "require"

Comment: I know this error `cant save new user: User validation failed: name: Path name is required., Password: Path password is required`. Have you done the `express.json()` change? That error wont come after this.

Comment: i tried express.json() and also bodyParser.json(). This error appears in both options.

Comment: Earlier I was also getting the error you mentioned. Then after I added express.json(), it worked. And also new keyword was missing before `mongoose.Schema()` so please double check once again your code. Because it should work now.

Comment: Also, before user1, `console.log(req.body)` and let me know the value.

Comment: the return value is empty curly brackets...  data is not inserted....

Comment: Yup. As expected. Its weird. Because it should work if you are using `app.use(express.json())` and selected raw json in Postman.

Comment: Have you set `Content-type` to `application/json` inside headers in Postman?

Comment: ya!!!!!! it was the problem!!!!

Comment: now it works!!! thanks, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make the following changes to get the desired result.

```
// In place of app.use(bodyParser.json()), use
app.use(express.json())
```

```
// Controller
const userSchema = require("../models/User");
const newUser = async (req, res) => {
  let user1 = new userSchema({
    name: req.body.name,
    password: req.body.password,
  });
  console.log(`${user1} added`);
  try {
    await user1.save().then(() => res.status(201).json({ newUser: user1 }));
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(`cant save new user: ${error.message}`);
  }
};
module.exports = { newUser };
```

Also, inside the user schema, please change `require` to `required: true`.

```
// Model
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        minLength:8,
        required: true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `model.js` file. It will check if anything is missing in req.body

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String, 
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        minlength:8,
        required: true
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```